# How to check for valid value before converting Decimal

Tags: c#

I assume this will blow up if total is null (I don't recall if decimals are initalized to null at the beginning or zero)

```
public int SomePropertyName
{
    get { return Convert.ToInt32(Decimal.Round(total)); }
}
```

So should I check for null or > 0 ?

Answer (score 5):

Decimal is a value type - there's no such value as "null" for a decimal.

However, it's perfectly possible for a decimal to be out of range for an `int`. You might want:

```
decimal rounded = decimal.Round(total);
if (rounded < int.MinValue || rounded > int.MaxValue)
{
    // Do whatever you ought to here (it will depend on your application)
}
return (int) rounded;
```

I'm somewhat confused as to why you're using `Convert.ToInt32` at all though, given that your property is declared to return a `decimal`. What's the bigger picture here? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Decimal is a value type and can not be null.

If you *need* to know if it had been initialized, you should probably use a nullable decimal:

```
Decimal? total = null;

public int SomePropertyName
{
    get 
    { 
        if (total.HasValue) Convert.ToInt32(Decimal.Round(total.Value)); 
        return 0; // or whatever
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Decimals are value types, and so cannot be null.

So no need to check there..

Comment: ok but I could get an error during conversion...it's possibly right?  What about checking for IntMin and IntMax?  Unecessary?

Comment: Go with Decimal.TryParse to prepare for errors during conversion.

Answer (score 1):

[System.Decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx) is a value type, so it cannot be null. Second thing, the method's return value is `decimal`, so why would you want to convert to a `Int32`?

Comment: why isn't really a question to ask but I will answer that.  Because for ever dollar they purchase, they get 1 reward point.  Reward points are integers.  I'm simply going to convert their total decimal dollar in the cart to Int to get this and round it up.  Otherwise return zero from the property.

Comment: Ok, in that case your property should simply return `int` as a result.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, Decimal is a value type and cannot be null.  However, if converting from a string then [Decimal.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557.aspx) is your friend...